# How I can save a Page in a Page Template in Kentico Xperience13

Tags: kentico

In Kentico Xperience13, when I go in the Page Template application they said we need to use the Page Application to create a page and save it as a Page Template. But when I create a Page I don't see the place where I can save as a Page Template. So when I came back in the Page Template application the list is always empty.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: I have the same question, I'm inserting a page using the API, however, I could not find a way to assign the Page Template. I get the following error: there is no page template registered for selected page. Did you find the provider to assign it?

Answer (score 2):

To use Page Templates in Kentico Xperience 13, you either need to create default templates through code - see [Developing page templates](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-page-templates), or you can save widgets that have been added to a page as a custom page template - see [Saving pages as custom page templates](https://docs.xperience.io/managing-website-content/using-page-templates#Usingpagetemplates-Savingpagesascustompagetemplates)

Comment: Just to add my 5 cents - the Page templates application mentioned in the question is used buy Portal engine, not in MVC. Just to avoid confusion :-)

Comment: In KX13/MVC you create pages in the Pages module, and then the custom page templates appear in the Page Templates application.

Answer (score 0):

As someone currently working on a site in Xperience 13, you may want to consider taking a class or two on Pluralsight to give you the basics of MVC and .net core. I am new to those but have been using Kentico for over 10 years. This change to MVC has been a bear to learn. But the Pluralsight courses have helped me get a better understanding of the structure.

Kentico does use content based routing as an option (and I think it is default in 13) you can learn more about it here https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/implementing-routing#Implementingrouting-Contenttree-basedrouting

when you build page types you don't have to worry about the model and the controller portion, kentico handles it, you just need to build the view.

this tutorial covers the basics https://docs.xperience.io/13tutorial/asp-net-core-development-tutorial